# Why will my After Effects script run from the menu but not from commandline?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I'm trying to run a .jsx file I've written from commandline, but it will not work. When I call `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2020\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -r script.jsx"` After Effects opens and quickly closes, without even modifying the project or appearing to do anything. When I click on File > Script > Run Script inside of AE, it works perfectly fine and the project saves. I also added some alerts to my script which trigger when called from the File menu but not from commandline, making it clear that nothing is happening. What's going on here?

Comment: The [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/after-effects/using/scripts.html) says "Use the -r switch and the _full path of the script_ to run as arguments: Example (for Windows): `afterfx -r c:\script_path\example_script.jsx`". What if you try passing the full, absolute path? Or the relative path, if in the same folder as AfterFX.exe with `afterfx.exe -r .\script.jsx` ?

Comment: I didn't include it here, but it is actually listed as the absolute path when I run it. Here's the exact command, directly from my program. 
`"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2020\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -s "C:\Users\letsd\Documents\app\resources\script.jsx"`